# ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed error = 2 on app start

Tags: iphone, crash, javax.imageio, libpng

i made an iphone app and build it with 5.0.
on 5.0.1 it works fine. when i try to open the app on 5.1 or 5.1.1 the app crashes instantly.

in the log there are the following entries:

`ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed '/Applications/myApp.app/Icon.png'
error = 2 (No such file or directory)
libpng error: No IDATs written into file`

i opened the folder and Icon.png exists!!

hope someone can help me :/

Answer (score 0):

Please add icon.png in your application plist file under the row **icon files**.[image]