# UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage) throwing libpng error : No IDATs written into file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata, uiimagepngrepresentation

I am creating an application in which i save the thumbnails from the browser. Everything is working fine till i tend to move the directory containing this file into the other directory.
It give this error:

> ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed '/Users/anuj/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/8CD8EB07-6D62-4284-B425-087E821098BC/Library/Caches/PausedVideos/Old School vs. New School/Thumbnail'
>            error = 2 (No such file or directory)
>   ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed '/Users/anuj/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/8CD8EB07-6D62-4284-B425-087E821098BC/Library/Caches/PausedVideos/Old School vs. New School/Thumbnail'
>            error = 2 (No such file or directory)
>   libpng error: No IDATs written into file

Heres the code that i am using:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(video.Thumbnail)];
Thumbnail = [[UIImage imageWithData:data] retain];
```

I also referred to the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652289/imageio-cgimageread-mapdata-open-failed-error-2-on-app-start) but that doesn't changed anything.

Comment: Nikhil, It seems that no image data was written which you were converting. Please check with the byte length of video.Thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageview.image)]
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
[yourImageView setImage:img];
```

Comment: i am doing the same thing and received the error on the very first line of code.